# UITabBar can't change selected index

Tags: ios, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm having trouble changing the index of my UITabBar.  I am attempting to change it from the UITabBarController subclass.  This is what I'm trying:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

This is what my .h looks like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTab : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
     IBOutlet CustomTab *bar;
}

@end
```

I am trying to set the index with an IBAction, the method is being called, but the index doesn't change.  Any ideas?

Comment: This works from the other viewcontrollers, does it have to do with being called from the UITabBarController itself?

Comment: Is the IBAction implemented inside CustomTab? Because if not you need to make sure that self.tabBarController is pointing to your CustomTab.

Comment: It is implemented inside CustomTab, I set up a button and add the action like so, `[button addTarget:nil action:@selector(change) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Is it possible to do just [self setSelectedIndex:1]; ?

Comment: Yep, thanks so much.  Knew it was something like that.  You can make this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

from inside the CustomTab class itself. You need to replace it with

```
[self setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: Lol. That one had me for a while too.. Easy to do!

Answer (score 0):

for swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self .selectedIndex = 3 // desired index
}
```