# Can't change tab inside tabBar(tabBar: didSelectItem item:)

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to toggle the selected tab when the user taps on tab. Let say if I have two tabs and the first is displayed, then tapping on first tab (as well as tapping on the second tab) should lead me to the second tab. I've implemented a custom UITabBarController as seen below.

```
class CustomizedTabBarContorller: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.selectedIndex = 1                 // this way works
    }


    override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

        if tabBar.items?.indexOf(item) == self.selectedIndex {
            self.selectedIndex = (selectedIndex == 0) ? 1 : 0  // doesn't work
        }
   }

}
```

How to change the tab, based on the selected and tapped tab?

I've also looked at:
[UITabBar can't change selected index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429140/uitabbar-cant-change-selected-index)
[UITabBarController Set a Default Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785010/uitabbarcontroller-set-a-default-tab-in-swift-language)
...and many others.

Comment: You are trying to dynamically change the view controller associated with the tab bar items?

Comment: No. Actually I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "dynamically", but I have my FirstViewController and my SecondViewController always on their position associated with the first and the second bar item. This doesn't change.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I have a tab bar controller with 2 tabs. When first tab is selected I like to show the second tab by just tapping on the first tab bar item. It's like toggle - when first is already visible, tapping on first tab should dismiss the first tab and show the second.

Comment: probably not the answer you are looking for, but I would avoid that as its not very standard iOS behavior but then again its not the craziest thing I've ever heard.

Comment: The default behaviour is very simple, when you tap on a desired tab bar item you're presented with the associated tab. And if you're already on the tapped tab you just stay there. Nothing happens. But I want to change this default behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116600/discussion-between-andrej-and-anders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0` to main queue solves the issue. Works like a charm.

```
if tabBar.items?.indexOf(item) == self.selectedIndex {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
        self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0
    } 
}
```